# How to iterate through polygons in matplotlib Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, shapefile, matplotlib-basemap

I have a shapefile with province polygons for China. There are 31 provinces in China, and my shapefiles' .csv and .dbf file both contain 31 rows when I open them in Excel.

However, when I try to iterate through them with the following code, I get some provinces repeated many times (with different polygon coordinates apparently). Why is that?

```
m = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=15,urcrnrlat=55,llcrnrlon=70,urcrnrlon=140,lat_ts=20,resolution='c')
    shp = m.readshapefile(china_shapefile, 'states', drawbounds=True)


for info, shape in zip(m.states_info, m.states):
    print info["NAME_1"]#NAME_1 is the province name in english 
    print shape[0]#First coordinate of the polygon to quickly check if they are repeated
```